# Django's Model.save() modifies undesired columns

Tags: python, sql, django

Recently I've found that Django ORM's `Model.save()` executes an SQL to update 'ALL' columns by default, even if nothing has been modified. 
This really concerns me, because any changes I made has a chance to be set back to the original value by some other `Model.save()` process.

For example, I have a model `Order`. And there are two concurrent processes (P1, P2) working on it. First of all, P1 selects a row:

```
# P1
order = Order.objects.get(pk=10000)
```

Then, P2 selects the same row and updates the `status` column: (the following statements can be wrapped in a transaction, or even a SERIALIZABLE one, but this can not solve the issue.)

```
# P2
order = Order.objects.get(pk=10000)
if order.status == UNPAID:
    order.status = PAID    # update the `status` column
    order.save()
```

After that, P1 updates some other trivial column:

```
# P1
order.xxx = xxx    # update some other trivial column
order.save()    # This would set the `status` back to UNPAID !!!
```

`order.status` would be set back to `UNPAID`, and that is NOT what I want.

I know I can use `save(update_fields=...)`, `select_for_update()`, `filter(...).update(...)`, SERIALIZABLE transaction, or explicit locking on P1 to prevent this issue. 
But the thing is: It's ridiculous to use them on all `Model.save()` statements in the whole project. Furthermore, even if I do in my project code, there's some other code doing this (Django Admin, ModelForm...).

Should I rewrite `Model.save()` to update only those modified fields?

(It seems like a severe problem to me. Or have I taken something wrong?)

Comment: It happens because `P1` has no idea that you changed `P2`'s `status` attribute. Why do you need 2 different references to the same `order`?

Comment: @DeepSpace I would think `P1` and `P2` are different processes.

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, they are different processes. For example, a staff is using Django Admin to modify that order (`P1`), and a customer is making a payment (`P2`).

Comment: So, this is a race condition, but you've already stated the various approaches for fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

As other folks said in comments, you have classic type of [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition). There are some ways of dealing this in Django. You've already mention some of this, but they can't be considered safety in my experience. I highly suggest you to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2ikLB1Ka3Q) called `Immutable Django` and start digging in this direction.

Basically you can add some kind of `version` column in your model and increment it in every save and compare to existing one. If new version is same or less then already saved one - you trying to save unactual entry.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one column for a similar race condition to happen:

```
# Process 1
account = Account.objects.get(pk=1)
account.balance += 1000

# Process 2
account = Account.objects.get(pk=1)
account.balance -= 10
account.save()

# Process 1
account.save()
```

Now the balance deduction from process 2 is lost. You *must* use `select_for_update` to ensure your writes are consistent. Even if you only save the "dirty" fields, and make that the default, this will still happen.